# C++ map poiting

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I'm trying to storage all variables in a map, to be able to easy create a print of the software variables, but I still cant make it works with map. Can someone help?

```
int ovalor = 10;
map<string, int> *mapping = new map<string, int>();
(*mapping)["ovalor"] = &ovalor;
```

> error: a value of type "int *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int"

thanks a lot

Comment: Your map takes `int` as value but you are trying to assign the adress of a `int` with `&int-value `which is `int*`

Comment: As an aside, don't allocate dynamically (with `new`) unless there's no other choice.

Comment: Also, in this example you are taking the address of a local variable. That address will not be valid outside the scope in which the variable resides.

Comment: Please avoid managing `new` and `delete` yourself. Usually you don't need that. Either instantiate the object on the stack, or use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` if you are sure you need dynamic allocation. C++ isn't Java.

Comment: Does nobody *read* error messages anymore?

Comment: Thanks all. Worked now.

map<string, int*> mapping;
mapping["ovalor"] = &ovalor;
cout << *mapping["ovalor"] << endl;
ovalor = 20;
cout << *mapping["ovalor"] << endl;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message says all it needs to really:

```
error: a value of type "int *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int"
```

because here:

```
(*mapping)["ovalor"] = &ovalor;
```

You are taking the address of `ovalor`, which gives you an `int *` and then trying to store it in a map that maps `string`s to `int`s. A pointer to an integer is not the same thing as an integer by a long chalk. Moreover, a pointer to a local variable (which this looks like) is just asking for trouble later on.

In passing, why the pointer stuff? It's be much simpler to just do

```
map<string, int> mapping;
```

and save you worries with dangling references and unfreed memory.